# How to create a date(day) intervals using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to create a `day` only `date` intervals:

```
Date_Ipsum
----------
2019-01-01
2019-01-10
2019-01-20
...
```

Here you can see that each `day` in the `Date_Ipsum` column has `interval of 10 days`.
I want to have the ability specify the `Start` and `End` and including the `intervals`.

**What did I do?**

The closet I came up with is this:

```
pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=100, freq="d")
```

But this solution does not have `intervals` or `Start` and `End`

Could some one please help me?

Comment: do you need a one-liner answer??

Comment: anything that will help me understand what is happening :)

Comment: start is the first date, end is the last date, and periods is the interval u r looking for

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
pd.date_range(start='2019-01-01', end='2020-12-31', freq="10d")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this, is it what you need? (I used sim_min_date and sim_max_date in my code)

```
pd.date_range(start=sim_min_date, end=sim_max_date, freq='d')
```

From the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html, there are quite a few arguments, including start and end.

Comment: `freq` should be `"10d"`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647778/1426065).